# React: get child component data from parent

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have a react component like below:

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
    <button type="button" />
</Parent>
```

`<Child />` has a `input[type="file"]` form control in it.

when I click the button in `<Parent />`, I want to upload the file in `<Child />` with ajax,

how can I access the `input[type="file"]` inside `<Child />`?

I tried using `refs`

```
<Parent>
    <Child ref="child"/>
    <button type="button" />
</Parent>
```

so that I can access the `input` by writing

```
this.refs.child.refs.file
```

but I do not think it's the best practice....

Answer (score 0):

In Parent:

```
_handleImageUpload(image) {
  this.setState({
    image: image
  });
}

<Child onImageUpload={this._handleImageUpload} />
```

In child:

```
_handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.onImageUpload(this.state.file);
}

_handleImageChange(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let file = e.target.files[0];

  reader.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState({
      file: file
    });
  }
}
```

Render from child:

```
<form onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}>
  <input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange} />
  <button type="submit" onClick={this._handleSubmit}>Upload Image</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your child component as a "[Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)".

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    inputValue: ''
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child onChange={this.onChange}></Child>
            <button onChange={this.onSubmit} type="button" />
        </div>
    );
  },

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  },

  onSubmit() {
    //do your ajax operation with this.state.inputValue here
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    inputValue: ''
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type='file'
        onChange={this.props.onChange} />
    );
  }
});
```

For detailed explanation go [here](http://www.jackcallister.com/2014/11/20/controlled-inputs-with-react-js.html)

Comment: In your case you dont need `getInitialState` in `Child` Component